# Why Do I Get "nested functions are disabled..." Error in my Code?

Tags: c, function

Basically, a program to find the **largest prime factor of a number**. Don't know if the logic is correct cuz I can't run it to test it. I know this is long. But please forgive me.

```
//largest_prime.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int num,large;
    int prime(int);
    int lprime(int);
    printf("Enter number: "); 
    scanf("%d",&num);
    large = lprime(num);
    printf("Largest Prime = %d\n",large);
    return 0;
}

int lprime(int num) {
    int i=num-1,large;
    while (i!=-1) {
        if (num%i==0) {
            if (prime(i)==1) {
                large=i;
                i=-1;
            }
            i--;
        }
        return large;
    }

    int prime(int num) {
        int prime,i=num-1;
        while (i!=-1) {
            if(num%i==0) {
                if(i!=1) {
                    i=-1;
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                    return 1;
            }
            i--;
        }
    }
```

I get this as output at terminal (I use Mac) using GCC:

```
largest_prime.c: In function ‘lprime’:
largest_prime.c:26: error: nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable
largest_prime.c:39: error: syntax error at end of input
```

I tried -fnested-functions to re-enable. I get:

```
largest_prime.c: In function ‘lprime’:
largest_prime.c:39: error: syntax error at end of input
```

Please Help!

Comment: Just as a note, this is why i hate Java-style braces (opening brace at the end of the previous row), you can't see at a glance which brace you're closing at your indentation level.

Comment: @Blindy: that's why we have IDEs, but point well taken.

Comment: @r0ach: why declare `prime` and `lprime` within `main`? Why not declare them before `main`, as is standard C style?

Comment: Having opening braces at the end of the previous row is far, far, older than Java, I might add.

Answer (score 10):

lprime is missing trailing '}' (in fact i believe you lost while's trailing '}')

Answer (score 6):

your are missing a }  after `return large;`

the compiler deduced you are beginning a new function declaration inside  `lprime`  hence 
the nested function error

Answer (score 3):

Functions cannot be nested in ISO C; enabling some compiler extension to allow then is not the solution; just make you code valid C.  Your indentation style is not helping you here; but the fact that the last line of each function is not at the left margin should ring alarm bells.  The following compiles but not without warnings (added lines marked):

```
//largest_prime.c
#include <stdio.h>

// Forward declarations
int lprime(int num) ;  //********************
int prime(int num) ;   //********************

int main() {
    int num,large;
    printf("Enter number: "); 
    scanf("%d",&num);
    large = lprime(num);
    printf("Largest Prime = %d\n",large);
    return 0;
}

int lprime(int num) {
    int i=num-1,large;
    while (i!=-1) {
        if (num%i==0) {
            if (prime(i)==1) {
                large=i;
                i=-1;
            }
            i--;
        }              //********************
    }
    return large;
}

int prime(int num) {
    int prime,i=num-1;
    while (i!=-1) {
        if(num%i==0) {
            if(i!=1) {
                i=-1;
                return 0;
            }
            else
                return 1;
        }
        i--;
    }
}
```

The warnings are:

```
main.cpp(34) : warning C4101: 'prime' : unreferenced local variable
main.cpp(46) : warning C4715: 'prime' : not all control paths return a value
```

I have not executed the code, so whether it works correctly is for you to determine.

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I did not notice those declarations in the "unconventional" location.  I added the previous declarations because I thought they were missing altogether.  The lesson being; don't write 'unusual' code.  And this is unusual in many ways!